# Comparing coefficients gone wrong. How do we know it's allowed?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question

Disclaimer: This is a problem I am currently working through. I do not wish for the solution, but rather a good detailed explanation about the topic of comparing coefficients, and why in my case (using the question as context) it did not work.

> Suppose $x$ satisfies $x^3 = 2x + 1$. We can uniquely write
> $$x^k = A_k + B_kx + C_kx^2 \tag1$$ for every integer $k \geq 0$,  where $A_k,B_k,C_k$ are integers. The question asks to prove that $A_{k+1}$=$C_k$, $B_{k+1} = A_k + 2C_k$, and finally $C_{k+1} =B_k$.

I started by multiplying both sides of the identity $(1)$ by $x$ to get $$x^{k+1} = A_k x + B_k x^2 + C_k x^3 \tag2$$
Then, by noting $(1)$ is valid for all natural $k$ its also valid for all $(k+1)$ where $k$ is natural, doing this gets
$$x^{k+1} = A_{k+1} + B_{k+1}x + C_{k+1}x^2 \tag3$$
We want these to be equivalent so we compare coefficients, giving $A_k = B_{k+1}$, $B_k = C_{k+1}$ and $A_{k+1} = C_k = 0$, which is not what we wanted to show.

My question to you is, why did this not work?

Comment: Not following.  You appear to have ignored the defining relation for $x$, namely $x^3=2x+1$.  Thus, if $x^k=A_k+B_kx+C_kx^2$ we have $x^{k+1}=A_kx+B_kx^2+C_kx^3=A_kx+B_kx^2+C_k(2x+1)=C_k+(A_k+2C_k)x+B_kx^2$ and now you can match.

Comment: Ah, we have to use the relation for $x$, my bad. Is there an intuitive reason as to why? How do we write what we are looking for in formallogic? Like using $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$ etc.

Comment: Again, not following.  We can't generally get such a nice expression for $x^k$. For $x=\pi$, say (or any other transcendental number) there is no such description.  Thus the relation is built into the problem.

Comment: 'equating of coefficients' works in general, because polynomials agree on all values of their domain if and only if they have the same coefficients for each power. That includes polynomials in more than one variable. To prove this, linear algebra is probably the most straight forward approach I believe.

Comment: Alright so when two polynomials say $f$ and $g$ agree for all $x$  say $f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + ..... $ and $g(x) = b_0 + b_1 x + ....$ we can write $a_0 = b_0$ and so on. Once again, how can we write what we are looking for in formal logic using quantifiers? Thanks!

Comment: Typo but indeed. And we define equality of functions by saying two functions are equal iff they agree on all input values - so actually, we are talking about equality of polynomials here.

Comment: Forget about matching coefficients.  It's really not relevant here (as the coefficients keep changing).  What I wrote shows that we can always find integers $A_k,B_k, C_k$ that work as required  (well, you have to check for $k=0,1,2$ but that's easy).  You still have to prove uniqueness though.

Comment: We can uniquely write $x^k = A_k + B_k x + C_k x^2$. This is not a guarantee that there does not exist, say $D_k, E_k, F_k$ such that $x^{k} = D_k x + E_k x^2 + F_k x^3$. The uniqueness specifically refers to being able to rewrite it as a quadratic. In general there will be many polynomials in $x$ equal to $x^k$ (which can be obtained through repeated application of $x^3 = 2x + 1$), but it is true that there will only be one *quadratic* polynomial equal to $x^k$ for each $k$.

Comment: To stress:  the $(A_k, B_k, C_k)$ are obviously not unique if you drop the requirement that they be integers.  For all $k$ you could take $A_k=x^k$, $B_k=0=C_k$.  That triple works too!  But you won't get integers that way.

Comment: Lulu could you type up everything you've discussed here into an answer and Ill mark it as a solution? If possible can you include some logic in there too (using quantifiers, and I am trying to learn how to use those too in my free time too).

Comment: It's maybe a bit silly, but I think some of the confusion here comes from using $x$ for a specific value (actually values), namely the roots of $x^3 - 2x - 1$ when $x$ is usually only used in the context of polynomials as a formal symbol that helps us keep track of how to multiply and add polynomials. If you write $\alpha$ instead of $x$ things may become more clear. Each expression involving x that you've written is a polynomial in $x$, not an abstract polynomial. There is a difference and it's a subtlety that's rarely relevant and often productive to ignore, but here you need to be careful.

Comment: No time now, sorry. Later.  But, again, nothing in what I wrote proves uniqueness.  For that you need to use the fact that $x$ doesn't satisfy and polynomial over $\mathbb Z$ of degree $≤2$.

Comment: Perhaps Charles, if you write up a solution using $\alpha$ instead of $x$, then I can see your point in more detail? Thank you both so much.